# Truffle config gas price confusion

Tags: truffle, contract-deployment, gas

I'm doing a dry run of a mainnet to get the total gas cost/

```
Replacing 'Migrations'
 > Total cost:         0.000343902 ETH

Replacing 'EthText'
> Total cost:         0.001205478 ETH

Summary
=======
> Total deployments:   2
> Final cost:          0.00154938 ETH
```

That's 1549380 Gwei.

The Truffle docs set the default value of gasPrice to `100000000000 (100 Shannon)`.

So, is Shannon the unit Truffle is expecting for gasPrice?
Do I need to convert the `1549380 Gwei` to Shannon?  Or is Gwei?

The docs are sort of confusing.

Answer (score 0):

The default unit used by Truffle in truffle-config.js is Wei (1 Wei = 10^(-18) Ether). You should set the `gasPrice` in this unit.

You can use this website for conversions : https://eth-converter.com/.